# Swift function produces a "SIGILL" on it's return statement

Tags: swift, linux, callback, urlsession

I am writing a piece of code in Swift to hit a public API endpoint to pull back data in JSON and use it in the application. I am using URLSession to do the request and am using an async/await similar paradigm to extract data out of the URLSession callback and place it in a local variable. Then, the function returns the optional dictionary returned by JSONSerialization to the caller.

This code executes perfectly fine outside of a function and run as part of the main program, but as soon as it is moved to a function, the return statement produces a "SIGILL" exit.

I breakpointed to the return statement and found that it is exactly what  is throwing this error. Since this is an optional dictionary, I tried just returning an unwrapped version of the dictionary and found the same results. I also tried just returning a blank dictionary and I still get a SIGILL

Functioning:

```c
let url = URL(string: <endpointURL>)!
var tenant: [String: Any]? = nil;
let sem = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)
sem.wait()
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
    if let data = data {
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
            if let json = json {
                print(json)
                tenant = json
                sem.signal()
            } else {
                print("ERR: Null JSON")
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("ERR: " + error.localizedDescription)
        }
    } else if let error = error {
        print("ERR: " + error.localizedDescription);
    } else {
        print("ERR: Unknown")
    }
}
print("resuming")
task.resume()
print("waiting: ")
sem.wait()
print("done waiting")

print(tenant!["tenant_name"]!)
```

Fails:

```c
let _ = HttpHelper.getTenantFor(tenantId: <someUUID>)
```

```c
class HttpHelper {
    static func getTenantFor(tenantId: String) -> [String:Any]? {
        let url = URL(string: <endpointURL>)!
        var tenant: [String: Any]? = nil;
        let sem = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)
        sem.wait()
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if let data = data {
                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
                    if let json = json {
                        print(json)
                        tenant = json
                        sem.signal()
                    } else {
                        print("ERR: Null JSON")
                    }
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print("ERR: " + error.localizedDescription)
                }
            } else if let error = error {
                print("ERR: " + error.localizedDescription);
            } else {
                print("ERR: Unknown")
            }
        }
        print("resuming")
        task.resume()
        print("waiting: ")
        sem.wait()
        print("done waiting")
        return [String:Any]()
    }
}
```

On the functioning code, the app outputs the proper value for the "tenant_name" key in the JSON object and in the failed code I get the following:

```
Process finished with exit code 132 (interrupted by signal 4: SIGILL)
```

Comment: Why two calls to `sem.wait()`?  There should only be one. Start the semaphore with a value of 0. But why use semaphores? Use a completion handler instead of a regular return value.

Comment: The first wait is to aquire the lock, then, the second wait will not be able to aquire the lock until it is released by the callback with ```signal()```. I want to avoid waiting and leaving all logic in the callback for style reasons on my end and my own strong preference for async/await as a paradigm rather than callbacks.

Comment: You do not need two calls to `wait`. One is enough if you initialize the semaphore with a value of 0. You need to embrace async. You are risking deadlocks and you are blocking when there is no need. There is a reason why completion blocks are used. Your preference is far from ideal.